# How to overlay contour plots on colormaps in gnuplot?

Tags: matrix, gnuplot, contour, color-mapping

I'm trying to create a colormap plot of datasetA with a contour plot of datasetB, both of which are read in from files.

The following successfully creates a colormap of datasetA:

```
plot 'valuesA.dat' matrix with image
```

I can draw contours as described [here](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/07/maps-contour-plots-with-labels.html).

How can I combine the two plots?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way do you want to combine the two plots? Wouldn't that render the result unreadable?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want to do.  To me, it looks like what you want is provided in the link above (simply substitute datasetB where he does the contouring of his original data in between the `set table` and `unset table` commands.)

Comment: Have a look at [gnuplot tricks](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/search?q=contour), where this is described in great detail. In the example, the same data is used but you may choose different data sets to obtain your desired result.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! (Sorry I didn't thank you sooner.) 

It was more complicated than I'd expected due to flexibility, but power comes in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, this is addressed at [gnuplot tricks](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/search?q=contour).

Comment: Sorry! I never really accepted your answer. I will now. I'm also adding an answer of my own for convenience and since I think it might be helpful for passers-by.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up doing it for an array of size 512x512 (for example). Suppose I have a datafile `A.dat` which is to be used for the colormap and `B.dat` for the contours.

- Create a table from `B.dat` containing the contour data and save it to a temporary file `temp.dat`.
- Plot the colormap using `A.dat` and plot the contour lines from the temp file `temp.dat` in a single command.

Here's my code (simplified somewhat for clarity):

```
# Set initial state
reset
set term X11
set palette @MATLAB    # see http://www.gnuplotting.org/matlab-colorbar-with-gnuplot/

# Create a file for contour data
set contour base
set cntrparam levels 25
set isosample 250,250
unset surface
set table "temp.dat"
splot "B.dat" binary array=512x512 format='%double'
unset table


# Plot the final results
set title "Contours and Colormap"
set size square
unset key
set xtics ('0' 0, '0.5' 255, '1.0' 511)   # Change these according to your dimensions
set ytics ('0' 0, '0.5' 255, '1.0' 511)   # Change these according to your dimensions

set cbrange [0.0:1.0]
set xlabel "X (scaled by height)"
set ylabel "Z (scaled by height)"


set terminal png
set output "output.png"
plot "A.dat" binary array=512x512 format='%double' with image, "temp.dat" with lines lt -1
```

To see what it looks like, I ended up using a scripted version of that code to produce [this movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe_f_mQCY6g) (and others) for my research!

Comment: How did you create your contour data file? What format does it have? And wouldn't it be possible to write the contour file such that it can be used directly without creating a temp file?

Comment: My code in this answer actually creates the contour file (`temp.dat`) in the paragraph called `# Create a file for contour data`. The first three lines set up what kind of contour plot I want, the `unset surface` tells gnuplot that I *only* want contour lines for this data -- no surface plot to go along with it. The `set table "temp.dat"` identifies the output contour file. The next line says to create the contour plot (which will be outputted as specified in the previous line) using a source datafile called `"B.dat"`, which is a binary data file with 512x512 double-precision values.

Comment: In the final line (starting with `plot`), you'll notice that it uses two input files: `"A.dat"` (which is the actual 2D color "image" plot I wanted), *plus* the `"temp.dat"` contour plot file. That tells gnuplot to do the contours superimposed on the 2D "image" plot. Does this all answer your question @Sjoerd2228888 ? More documentation on contour plotting is available here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node168.html.